# Php script for multiple file upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I am making a Cpanel for a open cart and I have to Upload 3 images of a product like this

```
<label for="password" class="control-label"><b>Product image:</b></label>
   <div class="controls">
<input type="file" name="Upload" id="password" class="span9 required" required />
</div>
<label for="password" class="control-label"><b>Product image:</b></label>
   <div class="controls">
    <input type="file" name="Upload" id="password" class="span9 required" required />

</div>

<label for="password" class="control-label"><b>Product image:</b></label>
   <div class="controls">
    <input type="file" name="Upload" id="password" class="span9 required" required />
</div>
```

I have searched many file upload code but none can make my work easy.
I am working in a Framework so I will send this data to database class:   `$this->mlogin->dbfunction($POST,$image1,$image2,$image3);`

where my insert query will execute

here is the database code

```
public function product_upload($_POST,$path) {

    $this->insert_query="INSERT INTO `_product`(
                                             `_p_name`,
                                             `_p_cat`,
                                             `_p_brand`,
                                             `_p_price`,
                                             `_p_amount`,
                                             `_p_image`,
                                             `_p_dcrp`

                                             )
                                             VALUES(
                                             '" .$_POST['name'] . "',
                                                 '" .$_POST['cat'] . "',
                                                     '" .$_POST['brand'] . "',
                                                         '" .$_POST['price'] . "',
                                                             '" .$_POST['avail'] . "',
                                                             '" .$path . "',
                                                                 '" .$_POST['detail'] . "'
                                                                 )";

    return $this->select();
}
```

Comment: which framework you are using ? Please explain your question deeply, what you require ?

Comment: its named as Code Petrol().look i will send other data from other  input field like $_POST['name'] ; but for image  i need a script so that i can pass as a parameter through function

Comment: Can you show us your script so far? How do you want to save the uploads? In your DB?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp is a great tutorial about this matter.

Comment: @RobertSeddon-Smith: [please don't refer to w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/), they have _no_ authority and provide outdated or [downright _wrong and dangerous_ documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) like inserting raw POST data in a DB (Injection is real, and one of the most common attacks)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from security concerns about unfiltered input, uploaded files are NOT found in $_POST but have a more complex layout found in $_FILES.

Simply do a var_output($_FILES) to check it's contents and refer to the documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Steps to keep in mind:

- set form enc type: enctype="multipart/form-data"
- Check $_FILES, not $_POST

Layout of $_FILES:

```
$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']  // The original name of the file on the client machine.
$_FILES[$fieldname]['type']  // The mime type of the file. Unsafe! Dont rely on it!
$_FILES[$fieldname]['size'] // The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.
$_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'] // The temporary filename of the file on the server.
$_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] // The error code associated with this file upload.
```